# Deleting folders from docker artifactory repository doesn't result in freed disk space

Tags: artifactory

What needs to happen to get artifactory to yield disk space after artifact deletion?

After using the following aql to find and then delete the `folders` I had Artifactory maintenance start `Cleanup Unused Cached Artifacts` and `Garbage Collection` (although the later is all I should need) and disk space remains at the same amount even though I deleted about 18,000 images.

- df -h continues to show the same space
- artifatory's admin/advanced/storage_summary continues to show the same number of artifacts.

What steps am I missing?

**Query**

`items.find(
        {
            "type": "folder",
            "repo": "docker-local",
            "name": {"$match":"unit*"},
            "created": {"$lt" : "2018-03-30"},
            "created": {"$gt" : "2017-08-30"}
        }
    )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deletions move artifacts from their repo into the `Trash Can` which can be emptied via [general-setttings: trash can settings](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Artifactory#ConfiguringArtifactory-TrashCanSettings).  After this, the [Garbage Collection](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Disk+Space+Usage) can be run.

Why isn't there a link between the trash can and maintenance in the app or the documentation?  That is an excellent question for which I've no answer.